# Where can I find "Mishnas Pikuach Nefesh"?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

Not sure if this kind of question is allowed on here. I've been looking for a specific sefer for a long time and I cannot find any seforim store that has it or that has even heard of it.

The sefer I am looking for is '[Mishnas Pikuach Nefesh' compiled by R' Lorincz](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?23534). It is about the halachos of pikuach nefesh.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yup, this question is on-topic here. Welcome to MY; I hope you stick around and enjoy the site! :)

Answer (score 6):

This sefer is available on the Otzar Hachochmah program.

You can also view the sefer here: https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?23534&

The first 40 pages are available for viewing for free. Beyond that you need to pay...